# Contact MailingAddress not geocoding after Data Integration rule turned on

Tags: contact, address, geocoding

I'm trying to goecode the MailingAddress for our Contact objects but the Lat/Long fields stay blank after turning on the Data Integration Rule. I've provided valid postcode, country, city and street name. This same data geocodes fine when used on a service territory object but not our contact.

I've bypassed triggers but the only thing I can think of is that the Contact is linked to a PersonAccount but I didn't think that would effect it. I know that you can't geocode Shipping or BillingAddress for PersonAccounts but does this also apply to related contacts?